# Cannot read resource files or refer them in Docker with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I use Spring Boot 2 and Thymeleaf as a frontend framework. And Thymeleaf is referring to templates that are located in `src/main/resources/template` folder. It is working fine. But when I try to run it in Docker my controller class cannot retrieve templates from resources.

How to make the `resources` folder available in Docker?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522649/how-to-reference-embedded-docker-resource-files-using-file-path-url